# I can't find version of Chromedriver to download that is the same version as my browser

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

The version of Chrome I have is Version 116.0.5845.180 but I cannot find this version in the Chromedriver downloads page https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Does anyone know where else I can download it from or any other solutions?
Can I download an older version of the webdriver?

Answer (score 0):

You can find some extra versions of chrome webdriver here
https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable

Comment: I don't think it has the version 116 as a chromedriver.exe file, at least I can't find it